# How to Show that the Fourier Series of 1-x, infinite sum of $\frac{2}{(n\pi)} \sin(n \pi x)$ equals 1 at x=0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I am confused how the Fourier sine series for 1-x, which is

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{(n\pi)} \sin(n \pi x)$

equals $1$ at $x=0$.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't—it evidently equals $0$ at $x=0$, since every summand vanishes there. When a function is discontinuous, its Fourier series doesn't necessarily equal the function.

Comment: (to guarantee the convergence to the function we need Dini's Criterion, stronger than continuity). For such a piecewise $C^1$ periodic function, at the discontinuities the Fourier series converges to the mean of the left and right limit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why is $1-x$ discontinuous at x=0? And wouldn't the left and right limit both be 1?